# MQJCA4004: Message delivery to an MDB 'null' failed with exception: 'deactivate of endpoint is in progress.'

Tags: queue, server, message-driven-bean

I have an EAR deployed on WAS 7.0.0.3 server and the web service also deployed.

MQ listener is up and running in my WAS server and corresponding MQ host, channel name and MQ queue name are configured correctly. It is the response queue.

Whenever I'm getting data from MQ, I'm getting the below error in SystemOut.log
error

> "MQJCA4004: Message delivery to an MDB 'null' failed with exception:
>   'deactivate of endpoint is in progress.'  "

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to further analyze similar `MQJCA4004` error using this, kinda hackish, technique.

You need a Java decompiler that preserves line numbers. 
[JadClipse](http://jadclipse.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) plugin for Eclipse can do that. Just make sure you have enabled:

```
Debug Settings
[x] Align code for debugging
```

in `Window > Preferences > Java > Decompiler`.

The standard Intellij Idea Community decompiler has that feature already enabled.

The IBM class responsible for producing the `MQJCA4004` error is

```
com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.AbstractWorkImpl
```

When you open it (with decompilation enabled) you'll be able to find the string `MQJCA4004`. Place a breakpoint there and start **remote debugging** your application server. When you hit that breakpoint, you'll gain access to all the context information including the exception (with call stack) that's causing this error.